# How do I reference a tkinter element created in __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to update the text in this scrollable area with these statements. I cannot figure out how to edit the elements created during the `__init__` in my class.

If I put the for loop into the `__init__` and hard code an entry, it will put all of the labels on the frame like I want it to, but when I try and update it after creation I am running into all kinds of issues.

I am not sure if I am even calling these functions or creating the classes the correct way so any input is appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont


class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        self.frames["StartPage"] = StartPage(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames["PageOne"] = PageOne(parent=container, controller=self)

        self.frames["StartPage"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames["PageOne"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))

        button1.pack()


class stored_functions():
    def get_date(self, entry):
        results = []
        for x in range(1,21):
            answer = int(entry) * x
            results.append([x, answer])
        PageOne.update_results(self, results)




class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        title = tk.Label(self, text='Enter a Number')
        title.pack()
        text = tk.Text(self, font=controller.title_font, width=8, height=1)
        text.pack()
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Get Multiplication Table",
                           command=lambda: stored_functions.get_date(self, entry=text.get('1.0', tk.END)))
        button.pack()

        divider = tk.Label(self, text='-------------------------------------------------')
        divider.pack()

        scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        scrollable_frame.config(width=50, height=100)
        scrollable_frame.pack()
        canvas = tk.Canvas(scrollable_frame)
        scroll_area = tk.Frame(canvas)
        scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(scrollable_frame, orient='vertical', command=canvas.yview)
        canvas.config(width=250, height=100, yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)
        canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        canvas.create_window((4,4), window=scroll_area, anchor='nw')

        header = tk.Label(scroll_area, text='Multiplication Table')
        header.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(10, 10), pady=10)

    def update_results(self, results):
        entry = results[0][1]
        row=2
        for i in results:
            statement = '{} multiplied by {} is {}.'.format(entry, i[0], i[1])
            statement_text = tk.Text(scroll_area)
            statement_text.grid(row=row, column=0)
            statement_text.configure(state='normal')
            statement_text.insert(tk.END, statement)
            statement_text.configure(state='disabled')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Assign it as an attribute of `self`, and then refer to it as such later? If you want to keep track of multiple things that are created in a loop, then make a list to store them. I don't understand what the actual difficulty is here.  At any rate, "when I try and update it after creation I am running into all kinds of issues." is not a problem that Stack Overflow can possibly help you with - please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question. Also, consider working through a Tkinter tutorial first.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a class with global variables, the variables need to be prefixed with `self.`. This lets the class know that the variable is it's own. Otherwise, they can only be accessed in the methods that they are defined in.

So, instead of typing `scroll_area = tk.Frame(canvas)`, you would type `self.scroll_area = tk.Frame(canvas)`. Do that will all your class's variables, and hopefully that'll work.

Comment: So if I call all of my variables self.variable then when I am referring to it from another class or function, do i need to use self in the call? I do not fully understand the "self" part of classes. Thanks

Comment: @Lzypenguin: To refer to them somewhere else, an instance of the class must have been passed as argument to this other place and therefore there will be an argument name associate with it, and that is what you would use instead of `self`. i.e. `arg1.scroll_area`.

Comment: @Lzypenguin: cont…In this software architecture, `controller=self`, so in other pages you can reference `controller.frames["PageName"].variable` to access those that are defined in the other `Page` classes by the name of the class they are in.

Comment: @Lzypenguin According to the [official document about classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html): *"Often, the first argument of a method is called self. This is nothing more than a convention: the name self has absolutely no special meaning to Python."*